# Open Sublime from cmd windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sublimetext3, git-bash

I can't open the sublime application or any file via within sublime from the command line. I am currently using Git Bash(SDK-64). I followed this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/open-sublime-text-from-the-command-line-using-subl-exe-windows). I am stumped I am still getting the bash error. **bash: subl.exe: command not found**

[image: Environment Variable]

[image: Enviroment Variable[2]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure, you have **`Program File`** folder in C directory? As far as I know C directory has **`Program Files`** folder. Add **s** in *Program File*.

Write **`C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3`** instead of **`C:\\Program File\Sublime Text 3`**. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Is necessary to only add your Sublime directory path to the `Path` list, as you have done in your first pic and use only one "`/`". 
Second step from last picture is not necessary.
Sublime will open with "subl.exe" and can take as argument the name of a file. "`subl.exe dummy.txt`".
I checked in Git Bash, Powershell and  Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 on win 10.